# How to show hide multiple div using Angular 8

Tags: javascript, angular

I want to show and hide multiple divs using JS in Angular 8. Below codes working fine on HTML mocks but not in Angular. In given below script when I'm clicking on the btn its showing

> Uncaught ReferenceError: divVisibility is not defined

Can I use this JavaScript? or is this only possible through typescript?

**COMPONENT HTML**

```html
<div class="row">
    <div class="col-sm-3">
        <a
            href="#"
            class="card"
            id="btnMoving"
            onclick="divVisibility('IdMoving');"
        >
            <div class="card-body text-center dashboard-moving-banner">
                <i class="simple-icon-control-forward text-white"></i>
                <p class="lead text-center text-white">18</p>
                <p class="card-text mb-0 text-white">Moving</p>
            </div>
        </a>
    </div>
</div>
```

**ANGULAR**

```js
import { Component, OnInit } from "@angular/core";

@Component({
    selector: "app-dashboard2",
    templateUrl: "./dashboard2.component.html",
    styleUrls: ["./dashboard2.component.scss"],
})
export class Dashboard2Component implements OnInit {
    constructor() {}

    ngOnInit(): void {
        var divs = ["IdMoving", "IdIdle", "IdRange", "IdStops"];
        var visibleDivId = null;
        function divVisibility(divId) {
            if (visibleDivId === divId) {
                visibleDivId = null;
            } else {
                visibleDivId = divId;
            }
            hideNonVisibleDivs();
        }

        function hideNonVisibleDivs() {
            var i, divId, div;
            for (i = 0; i < divs.length; i++) {
                divId = divs[i];
                div = document.getElementById(divId);
                if (visibleDivId === divId) {
                    div.style.display = "block";
                } else {
                    div.style.display = "none";
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Why do you have functions declared *inside* of the `ngOnInit` lifecycle hook?

Answer (score 2):

You are not using Angular propertly. Use `NgClass` for hide/show, or `ElementRef` https://angular.io/api/core/ElementRef but it´s the last resort.
If you are new in Angular, try to do [the Heroes Tutorial](https://angular.io/tutorial), you will learn how to do these things.